# How to create a map of <id, member function>?

Tags: c++

I have the following code in which I create a map of pointers to member functions.

```
class A {
 public:
  A() {
    m[0] = &A::F1;
    m[1] = &A::F2;
  }
  void F1(int v) { ... }
  void F2(int v) { ... }
  void O(int i, int v) {
     (*m[i])(v);
  }
 private:
  using func = void(A::*)(int);
  std::map<int, func> m;
};
```

But there is a compiling error in "O". In my understanding, "m[i]" is a pointer to member function, (*m[i]) dereferences it and should call the corresponding member function. But it does not work.

- Could you please help to explain it?
- Are there other neat ways to create a map of member functions?

Comment: You *could* use `std::map<int, std::function<void (int)>>`.

Comment: "there is an error". Please post the error message.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `std::function<void (int)>` alone would still have the same problem, you would need to connect the object on which the member function should be called with that function. So without mentioning `std::bind` this is not really helpful.

Comment: @t.niese Sure, you need `std::bind` or a lambda when adding entries to the map. But that isn't terribly difficult to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pointer to a member function only holds the pointer to the function, but not to the object on which it should be called.

You need to call that member function on an object:

```
(this->*m[i])(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could accomplish the same (arguably easier to read than plain function pointers) is with `std::function`, example:

```
class A {
public:
  A() { // implicit capture of this is deprecated in c++20
    m[0] = [this](int v) { F1(v); };
    m[1] = [this](int v) { F2(v); };
  }

  void F1(int v)        { std::cout << "F1: " << v; }
  void F2(int v)        { std::cout << "F2: " << v; }
  void O (int i, int v) { m[i](v);                  }

private:
  std::map<int, std::function<void(int)>> m;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.O(0, 5);
}
```